# How to concatenate string in a scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray using @tailrec?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

I need to concatenate strings present inside a WrappedArray in Scala. I am able to do it with the help of `List` but that is not what I have to do. I want a solution specifically designed for WrappedArray and with scope of adding/deleting elements while concatenating. I have to use this function as a udf for transforming data via Spark SQL `collect_list`. That is why I am forced to use WrappedArray.

For e.g ->

```
WrappedArray("I","love","coding")
Output : String = I : love : coding
```

This is just an example like adding a colon. I am facing various type issues while matching in case of Wrapped Array.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object tailRecursionString {

  def getString(ints :scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]): String = {
    @tailrec
    def sumAccumulator(ints: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], accum: String): String = {
      ints match {
        case Nil :  => accum
        case x :: tail => sumAccumulator(tail, accum + x)
      }
    }
    sumAccumulator(ints, "[") + "]"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String] = Array("kumar","sambhav","is","a","good","boy")
    val sum = getString(list)
    println(sum)
  }

}
```

Comment: **WrappedArray,** is not a type you should be using, it is an implementation detail. Also, **Arrays** are not intended for recursive algorithms. So, why insisting in not using the correct types for your problem? Is this for learning or is this for a real project?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually in spark 1.6, this is the type returned by collect_list function. That is the reason of using this. Yes this is for a real project.

Comment: If this is a for a real project then use `mkString` the recursive solution is very inefficient.

Comment: WrappedArray is not  "returned" by collect_list, its the runtime-type of Sparks `array` if passed to an UDF. Normally I write my UDF to take `Seq` (which works because WrappedArray is a Seq)), as I don't want the entire code to be cluttered with WrappedArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problems is using `WrappedArray` which hasn't `unapply` method. Pattern matching works using `unapply` method, you can read more about this in [scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). Just replace WrappedArray to Array and matching expressions then it should works:

```
@tailrec
def sumAccumulator(ints: Array[String], accum: String): String = {
  ints match {
    case Array()  => accum
    case _ => sumAccumulator(ints.tail, accum + ints.head)
  }
}
```

`List` has subtypes `::` and `Nil`. They are case classes and case classes have `unapply` method generated by compiler.

Shortly, I try to describe how it works:
When compiler looking for extracting (in pattern matching) it looks at `::`, sees that it's a subtype of `List` and has `unapply` method, and if `unapply` returns correct result it's choose this branch. The same way for `Nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You  could write it for `Seq` in general :

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def getString(ints :Seq[String]): String = {
  @tailrec
  def sumAccumulator(ints: Seq[String], accum: String): String = {
   ints match {
     case Seq(x)  => accum
     case  Seq(x, xs@_*) => sumAccumulator(xs, accum + x)
   }
 }
 sumAccumulator(ints, "[") + "]"
```

}

As `WrappedArray` is also a `Seq`, this will work

Answer (score 1):

```
val seperator = " "
s"[${scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray("I", "love", "coding").mkString(seperator)}]"
```

In case if you want to apply a filter, you can still use filter, and achieve the same.

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lttp77S4Sout7VWkOXTEhQ.js"></script>
```